# Side effects of throwing an exception inside a synchronized clause?

Tags: java, exception, synchronized

Are there any unclear side effects to throwing an exception from within a synchronized clause?
What happens to the lock?

```
private void doSomething() throws Exception {...}

synchronized (lock) {   
    doSomething();       
}
```

Answer (score 113, accepted):

I see no side-effect.

The **lock is guaranteed to be terminated** in all cases, and an exception is no exception (pun intended).

Comment: +1 for giving evidence, that sometimes an exception is not an exception :-))

Comment: @KLE what about an error? What happens if the code throws Stackoverflow or OutOfMemory?

Comment: [This page](http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=245377) is also worth a look, just FYI.

Comment: Like the finally clause!

Comment: In case of nested synchronized block on 2 different objects if exception is thrown inside the inner synchronized block, will the lock be released from both the object?

Answer (score 46):

As you would hope, the lock is released normally.

For reference, the appropriate section of the JLS which guarantees this behaviour is [§ 14.19](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/statements.html#14.19):

> If execution of the Block completes normally, then the lock is unlocked and the synchronized statement completes normally. If execution of the Block completes abruptly for any reason, then the lock is unlocked and the synchronized statement then completes abruptly for the same reason.

('abrupt completion' is defined elsewhere in the JLS to include exceptions from JVM, exceptions raised by `throw`, and use of the `break`, `continue`, or `return` statements to transfer outside the block.)

Comment: if `doSomething();` throws a java.lang.StackOverflowError what happens?