# Is synchronized keyword exception-safe?

Tags: java, exception, synchronized, exception-safe, exception-safety

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Side effects of throwing an exception inside a synchronized clause?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2019339/side-effects-of-throwing-an-exception-inside-a-synchronized-clause)

I am wondering if `synchronized` is exception-safe? Say, an uncaught exception happens within the synchronized block, will the lock be released?

Comment: In any scoped thread-safe block, the moment you get out of it, the thread-safety is gone.

Comment: Do you mean "Is the `synchronized` construct *exception-safe*?"?

Answer (score 8):

When in doubt, check the [Java Language Specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/).  In section [17.1](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/memory.html#17.1) you'll find:

> If execution of the method's body is ever completed, either normally
>   or abruptly, an unlock action is automatically performed on that same
>   monitor.

Answer (score 2):

1. Synchronize is neither thread-safe nor non-thread-safe.  The way you phrased the question just doesn't make sense.
2. In case of an exception the lock will be released.

Comment: +1 - The first part of the question is nonsensical.  OP - please review the definition of "thread safe".

Answer (score 1):

Only a System.exit prevents a block exiting normally.  It means `finally` blocks are not called and locks are not released.

```
private static final Object lock = new Object();

public static void main(String... args) throws ParseException {
    Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Locking");
            synchronized (lock) {
                System.out.println("Locked");
            }
        }
    }));
    synchronized (lock) {
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

prints

```
Locking
```

and hangs. :|

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it will. The major point of the synchronize keyword is to make multi-threaded coding easier.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8375172/java-synchronization-and-exception-handling deals with this specific case.

Answer (score 0):

Yes the object will become unlocked if an exception is thrown and not caught.

You can find some [code examples here.](http://www.artima.com/insidejvm/ed2/threadsynch3.html)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it will.

As a side note, the `try-finally` construct will ensure the finally block will be executed when the try exits

```
try {
    someFunctionThatMayThrow();
} finally {
    willAlwaysBeExecuted();
}
```